# Operation on each distinct row in a temp table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where I am doing something like below:

```
DECLARE @RemainingCount INT
DECLARE @DeletedUser Table(
    UserID NVARCHAR(100))

DELETE esi
OUTPUT Deleted.UserID INTO @DeletedUser(UserID)
FROM dbo.TableA esi
WHERE esi.UserID = @UserID --@UserID is one of the parameters passed to the SP
AND esi.ColumB = @ColumnBValue --@ColumnBValue is another parameter to the SP

SELECT @RemainingCount =  COUNT(*) 
FROM TableA es 
INNER JOIN @DeletedUser du ON es.UserID = du.UserID

IF @RemainingCount = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE at
    SET at.TotalUsers = at.TotalUsers - 1
    FROM TableB at
    WHERE at.TotalUsers > 0 
      AND at.[key] = @SomeParam --@SomeParam is another parameter to the SP
END
```

Here instead of calling the last update on all the remaining counts for the UserIds present in the `@DeletedUser` table, I want to loop through the `@DeletedUser` table and do below for all the distinct UserID in `@DeletedUser` table:

```
SELECT @RemainingCount =  COUNT(*) 
FROM TableA es 
INNER JOIN @DeletedUser du ON es.UserID = du.UserID

IF @RemainingCount = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE at
    SET at.TotalUsers = at.TotalUsers - 1
    FROM TableB at
    WHERE at.TotalUsers > 0 
      AND at.[key] = @SomeParam --@SomeParam is another parameter to the SP
END
```

So basically I want to calculate the `@RemainingCount` for every `UserID` in `@DeletedUser` table. How can I do that?

Comment: Huh? How could `@RemainingCount` ever be non-zero? You delete from `TableA` based solely on equality with the value of the `UserID` column and output that same column into a temp table. You then query the table again to locate any rows which have that same `UserID` value (except it's now coming from the table variable)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever My bad. To hide some info I just removed that part of the Where clause. Updated it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `INNER JOIN`, your `RemainingAmout` will nerver be 0.

You don't need loop through all UserId in DeletedUser.

As my understand, this query should work

```
SELECT @RemainingCount =  COUNT(DISTINCT de.UserId) 
FROM @DeletedUser de
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableA es WHERE es.UserId = de.UserId)

IF @RemainingCount > 0
BEGIN
   UPDATE at
   SET at.TotalUsers = at.TotalUsers - @RemainingCount
   FROM TableB at
   WHERE at.TotalUsers > 0 
    AND at.[key] = @SomeParam --@SomeParam is another parameter to the SP
END
```